# -webkit-animation/keyframes not playing nicely with -webkit-filter blur

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, css-animations

I'm trying to create an animated blur effect. I'd like for the background image to slowly become blurred. I'm trying to use `@-webkit-keyframes` to achieve this, but only the animated opacity is working.

Here's a live sample: http://codepen.io/dylnclrk/pen/cvDfx

And a brief description of what I'm doing:

My mixin for blur:

```
@mixin blur($radius) {
  -webkit-filter: blur($radius); 
  -moz-filter: blur($radius); 
  -o-filter: blur($radius);
  -ms-filter: blur($radius); 
  filter: blur($radius);
}
```

My Animation keyframes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes image_blur {
    0% { 
          @include blur(0px);
          opacity: 1;
        }
    50% { 
          @include blur(0.2px);
          opacity: 0.96;
        }
   100% { 
          @include blur(0.4px);
          opacity: 0.92;
        }
}
```

The animation:

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation: image_blur 1s; 
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.card').click(function () {
            $('.letter__picture').toggleClass('animated')
            $('.letter__text').toggleClass('visible', 1000);
         })
```

EDIT: I know one way to do this just by blurring the image with Photoshop and making a sprite. And then adjusting the opacity of the blurred
Image. But I'd like to see how I can do this with the browser's blur filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay it seems like *Chrome doesn't like having both an opacity rule and a filter together*.

Thanks to reddit's [/u/akaBruce](http://www.reddit.com/r/css/comments/1or6wr/help_with_webkit_keyframe_animations_with_blur/ccutpx4) For bringing [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166838/css-de-blur-an-image-while-fading-it-in/19168041#19168041) to my attention.

Looks like what I want to do is take my keyframe rules which looked like this:

```
opacity: 0.92;
-webkit-filter: blur(1px);
```

And take 'em full `filter`:

```
-webkit-filter: opacity(92%) blur(1px);
```

Seems pretty reasonable.

Here's a [forked codepen](http://codepen.io/dylnclrk/pen/vojbw) where I fixed the problem. Now all I have to do is get rid of the flicker (help?)...

Comment: I think that the flicker (don't know why) is caused by the Codepen itself. It works ok in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2nVRe/